# Laravel authentication works fine in localhost but shows different behavior in web host

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, webserver, localhost

The laravel authentication works fine in localhost in my computer but when I upload to the server , sometimes I can go in the area where authentication is required with out going through login. And sometimes it asks for login but logout doesn't work. I have looked over multiple sites for the solution but I couldn't solve it. And haven't found any applicable answer. I have re uploaded the code but again I am having same problem. In local it work just fine. I have been using the laravel 5.2 default auth and as of local machine I am using wamp in windows machine.The storage folder have 777 permission.

Comment: can you provide a bit more, server conf., local machine conf. login and logout methods. user login providers?

Comment: the login logout is of default laravel auth and I am using wamp for development purposes

Comment: try to look at the log in the live server.. looks like is not being able to write or read if the sessions are not being saved.. does the storage folder had the right permissions?

Comment: yes the storage folder have 777 permission

Comment: and there is no error log in server

Comment: Are you using Middleware? Please show some code you are using

Comment: as it is working in localhost I was confused which part of the code I show here. Ya I am using the default Middleware

Comment: we can't help unless we can see the code. Just share all of the code that you use for this authentication

Comment: I don't know how but it started working